# How to refer to BG-color, used by some Windows elements (scrollbar, pushed-in option button, etc.)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, systemcolors

Does anybody know how can I reference in C# a system background color, used on elements like scrollbar or pushed-in option button or tab (as the background for 'tabPage1' in the image below)?
Or, if no predefined const exists, any algorithm how to create a Brush with this color?  Thank you!

[image: background for tabPage1 indicates desired color]

My intuitive first choice `SystemColors.ScrollBar` results in same as `.Control`  or `.ButtonFace` (BG for 'tabPage2'), which is really a "face" color for the scrollbar, not what I'd call "background".
`SystemColors.ControlLight` or `SystemColors.ControlLightLight` do not get any closer..

When zoomed in, that area of the control looks like a checker-board with `.Control` and `.Window` pixels, so to me that hints at a possibility of this color being dithered;  maybe that indicates the reason why standard `SystemColors` enum does not define it?  How would I apply it to another control?

[image: zoomed-in view exposes the dithering]

P.S.: I'm trying to enhance a custom TabControl (which supports disableable tabs - another good thing missing from std controls, but that's another and already solved story), so that when its `.Appearance` is set to `Buttons` or `FlatButtons`, it looks similar to the original (illustrated above).   Selected tab is indicated by a pushed-in button, but its background color is set to  `Control` or `ButtonFace`:

[image]

Comment: Do I understand properly that you just want to change the system colors and set up them on your forms controls?

Comment: No, I want to refer to a system color (if that is one..), which is not listed in `SystemColors` enum, and use it on a control.  
If Windows theme is customized so that `.Control` color is, say, cyan, the controls I listed in the Q will have a lighter shade of cyan - so this "color" has to be derived from the main one (that may be the reason it is not declared explicitly).  What I want is a way to apply it to a control on my WinForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this turns out to be a lot simpler than I thought - it's just about the `Brush`, used to fill the BG-rect:

```
protected override void OnDrawItem( DrawItemEventArgs e )
{
    base.OnDrawItem( e );

    int         i=  e.Index;
    TabPage     p=  this.TabPages[ i ];
    Rectangle   r=  GetTabRect( i );
    Brush       br= null;

    if(  this.Appearance != TabAppearance.Normal  &&  i == this.SelectedIndex  )
        br= new HatchBrush( HatchStyle.Percent50, SystemColors.Control, SystemColors.Window );
    else
        br= new SolidBrush( p.BackColor );

    try                     // fill the BG-rectangle
    {   e.Graphics.FillRectangle( br, r );      }
    finally
    {   br.Dispose( );  }   // make sure brush is disposed of

    ..  // the rest of the event-handler
}
```

The only trick is that a `using( Brush br= new .. ) {..}` block cannot be applied, as initialization differs with resulting object type.  Hence, a somewhat ugly `try-finally` construct.  Works as a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't know Forms very well, but MFC has a function for providing such dithered bitmaps ([AfxGetDitheredBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6syzcy6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)), so I assume you'll have to do something similar.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a .Net equivalent function, sorry.